# Issue with booting Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, server

Fresh install of rails 4.2.4 and ruby 2.2.3. Every time I try to boot a server, I run into this error.  I've posted my development.rb file below as well.  Something seems to have gone amuck in my ROR install, but I can't figure out what it is.    Any ideas? Thanks guys!

```
Exiting
/Users/Rick/Desktop/RevMatchSite/forum_searcher/config/environments/development.rb:32:in fetch: key not found (KeyError)
from /Users/Rick/Desktop/RevMatchSite/forum_searcher/config/environments/development.rb:32:in block in <top (required)>
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in instance_eval
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in configure
    from /Users/Rick/Desktop/RevMatchSite/forum_searcher/config/environments/development.rb:1:in <top (required)>
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in require
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in block in require
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in load_dependency
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in require
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:598:in block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:597:in each
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:597:in block in <class:Engine>
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in instance_exec
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in run
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in block in run_initializers
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in block in tsort_each
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in each_strongly_connected_component_from
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in block in each_strongly_connected_component_from
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in each
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in tsort_each_child
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in each_strongly_connected_component_from
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in block in each_strongly_connected_component
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in each
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in each_strongly_connected_component
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in tsort_each
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in run_initializers
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in initialize!
from /Users/Rick/Desktop/RevMatchSite/forum_searcher/config/environment.rb:5:in <top (required)>
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in require
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in block in require
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in load_dependency
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in require
    from /Users/Rick/Desktop/RevMatchSite/forum_searcher/config.ru:3:in block in <main>
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in instance_eval
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in initialize
    from /Users/Rick/Desktop/RevMatchSite/forum_searcher/config.ru:in new
from /Users/Rick/Desktop/RevMatchSite/forum_searcher/config.ru:in <main>
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in eval
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in new_from_string
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in parse_file
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in build_app_and_options_from_config
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in app
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in app
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in wrapped_app
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in log_to_stdout
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in start
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in block in server
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in tap
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in server
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in run_command!
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in <top (required)>
from /Users/Rick/Desktop/RevMatchSite/forum_searcher/bin/rails:8:in require
    from /Users/Rick/Desktop/RevMatchSite/forum_searcher/bin/rails:8:in <top (required)>
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in load
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in call
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in call
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in run
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/bin/spring:49:in <top (required)>
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in load
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in <top (required)>
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in require
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in require
    from /Users/Rick/Desktop/RevMatchSite/forum_searcher/bin/spring:16:in <top (required)>
from bin/rails:3:in load
    from bin/rails:3:in <main>
```

**Several people have requested my development.rb file.  Please see below.**

```
    Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = false

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000}
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: ENV.fetch("SMTP_ADDRESS"),
    authentication: :plain,
    domain: ENV.fetch("SMTP_DOMAIN"),
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    password: ENV.fetch("SMTP_PASSWORD"),
    port: "587",
    user_name: ENV.fetch("SMTP_USERNAME")
  }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: ENV["SMTP_DOMAIN"] }
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  # config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  # config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

Comment: May you paste here your `config/environments/development.rb` file?

Comment: Please show your `config/environment/development.rb` file

Comment: Error generated by this line: /config/environments/development.rb:32:

Comment: It looks like you don't have set `SMTP_ADDRESS` as `ENV` variable

Comment: @Aguardientico I want to run this server locally.

Answer (score 0):

Method `fetch` requires the presence of a key, just replace it to simple brackets:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"],
  authentication: :plain,
  domain: ENV["SMTP_DOMAIN"],
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  password: ENV["SMTP_PASSWORD"],
  port: "587",
  user_name: ENV["SMTP_USERNAME"]
}
```

For not existing key it returns `nil`. Of course if you want to not define that configuration options.